# PHP sum how to call from other php file

Tags: php

I have 3 php files bonus, salary, and salary list.

1. for bonus is I count it everyday so for each employee have different bonus.
2. In salary part each employee have same salary.
3. In salary list part it'll show **Employee name, month, Salary and bonus** I already create relation between bonus and salary.
4. so in salary part I input **name, date(but only month and year), and salary**
5. In bonus part I have  **name(which relate to salary name),Period (which relate to salary date),date(mm-dd-yyyy), and cbonus**.

So the problem is in Salary list file I want to show **cbonus** but like I mention before in number **1** everyday there's bonus for employee.

my friend told me to use **PHP Sum** but after check the code I still don't understand.

Sorry I'm still new with this coding stuff.

I take a look from this site but still don't understand https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_sum.asp

```
<?php
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()): ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo date_format(date_create($row['month']),"F Y"); ?></td>
<td align="right"><?php echo number_format($row['salary'],0,".",","); ?></td>


<!-- bonus sum -->



<!-- -->

<td align="right"><?php echo number_format($row['cbonus'],0,".",","); ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

What kind of results I want to get is

in Salary list **showing bonus part** is total from all I input from **cbonus**

example

employee a - August 2019 - $10 - bonus (**cbonus** total from bonus he get from **august 2019 day 1-31**)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to make a array of bonus before while loop because if you want to use the array_sum it run once to calculate all values of array example:

```
$bonus=array(
'aug1' => 5,
'aug2' => 15,
'aug3' => 25
);
$bonus_data = array_sum($bonus); // it will give you 45
```

now put that in your code, whatever the format you use

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()): ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo date_format(date_create($row['month']),"F Y"); ?></td>
<td align="right"><?php echo number_format($row['salary'],0,".",","); ?></td>


<!-- bonus sum -->

<td align="right"><?php echo $bonus_data; ?></td>

<!-- -->

<!--<td align="right"><?php echo number_format($row['cbonus'],0,".",","); ?></td>-->
</tr>
```